# Rancher Traefik and Lets Encrypt with two domains

Tags: lets-encrypt, traefik, rancher

I have two containers running in rancher 1.6.25, behind a traefik load balancer, Version 1.7.9. Not using the built-in Let's Encrypt function. It is my understanding that I can't use the built-in LE support since I have two LE accounts.

One container is hosting www.domain1.com and the other is hosting www.domain2.com.  I have two Let's Encrypt containers running which are generating the certificates. (I have to have two because each certificate belongs to a separate Let's Encrypt account). Both are configured to save files to /shared/drive/LE/production.

How do I tell traefik to look to this drive for certificates?  Should I just mount the directory inside the Traefik container somewhere?

I have searched high and low and have not been able to find a solution for this exact scenario.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps better asked on devops SE ?

Comment: What is devops SE?

Comment: SE stand for stackexchange. In this case it would be https://devops.stackexchange.com

Comment: I will ask it over there.  I see that it is still in beta, so I am going to leave it here as well.

Comment: Well, I can't post over there until after I wait 40 minutes. Plus the tags i need do not exists and I am too new to make new tags. Need traefik and lets-encrypt.

Comment: I'd really recommend the rancher user slack - lots of people who know Rancher 1.6 there.  slack.rancher.io -